openApi generator erro with java
public CreateUserAccountRequest qradarAllowedDomainIds(List qradarAllowedDomainIds) {
    this.qradarAllowedDomainIds = qradarAllowedDomainIds;
    return this =;
    }

        public CreateUserAccountRequest addQradarAllowedDomainIdsItem(String qradarAllowedDomainIdsItem) {
                if (this.qradarAllowedDomainIds == null) {
                this.qradarAllowedDomainIds = new ArrayList<>();
                }
            this.qradarAllowedDomainIds.add(qradarAllowedDomainIdsItem);
            return this =;
        }

When I changed the generator version for all objects, it is generating this syntax error

Not clear what the error is. Can you add the error message

When I changed the generator version for all objects, it is generating this syntax error.
the error occurs right after updating the openApi version to 7.4 in the previous version the error does not occur, the yaml file is unmodified.
